# Why can't I import Mobaxterm sessions from file?

Tags: mobaxterm

I can export these just fine, but when I go to import them, they don't show up in the import file chooser dialog box. I can see the exported sessions when I export a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, having exported a session to a moba file, I was unable to import it again.

I solved this by dragging the moba file in mobaxterm's executable (same as 'open with...'), which opened and added the session to mobaxterm (even though it was already running).

Hope this helps.

Comment: this still works

Answer (score 0):

Copy "inf" file to & start the MobaXterm it will import your sessions !

```
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MobaXterm\home
```